# Xcode GoogleCast problem with CFBundleExecutable at Archieve App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, archive, chromecast

Hello I'm Making a Sound App integrated with ChromeCast in Obj-C. I use ChromeCast 4.4.7 dynamic SDK.
I use the manual method adding the SDK, and everything works fine. The app Connects with Chromecast and sends info.
The problem is what I want to Achieve the Project, using the strip_unused_archs.sh joined with the SDK. I've got 6 errors.
I Paste them

The domain/default pair of (/Users/juanjocontreras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMYA_Radio-fzjavmckasiwebglravdbxefwoel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/WMYA/Info.plist, CFBundleExecutable) does not exist
Removing unused architectures from framework: 
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/juanjocontreras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMYA_Radio-fzjavmckasiwebglravdbxefwoel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/WMYA/ (No such file or directory)
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: /Users/juanjocontreras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMYA_Radio-fzjavmckasiwebglravdbxefwoel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/WMYA/_armv7 (No such file or directory)
mv: rename /Users/juanjocontreras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMYA_Radio-fzjavmckasiwebglravdbxefwoel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/WMYA/_thinned to /Users/juanjocontreras/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WMYA_Radio-fzjavmckasiwebglravdbxefwoel/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/WMYA/: No such file or directory
2020-05-18 16:11:30.130 defaults[10081:96863] 
The domain/default pair of (Radio/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Ibiza1Radio.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/Info.plist, CFBundleExecutable) does not exist
Removing unused architectures from framework: 
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: Radio/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Ibiza1Radio.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/ (No such file or directory)
fatal error: lipo: can't open input file: Radio/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Ibiza1Radio.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/_armv7 (No such file or directory)
mv: rename Radio/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Ibiza1Radio.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/_thinned to Radio/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Ibiza1Radio.app/Frameworks/GoogleCast.framework/: No such file or directory

Any idea of what can I do to Archive and publish the app?
Thnx to all of U

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Same issue here and can't find anyone with the same issue / solution.